# Get new reference to jQuery DOM element

Tags: jquery, parameters, lightbox

I am using a lightbox script that I found. I am calling it inline with

```
javascript:lightbox(mycontent)
```

The works fine. mycontent is assigned like this:

```
mycontent = $('#mycontent');
```

So I click the anchor, this loads the lightbox with my content in. Great. But when I update my content (change some of the field values, for example), this does not affect the content within my lightbox.

Here is the lightbox script I am using:

```
function lightbox(insertContent, ajaxContentUrl) {
    // add lightbox/shadow <div/>'s if not previously added
    if ($('#lightbox').size() == 0) {
        var theLightbox = $('<div id="lightbox"/>');
        var theShadow = $('<div id="lightbox-shadow"/>');
        $(theShadow).click(function (e) {
            closeLightbox();
        });
        $('body').append(theShadow);
        $('body').append(theLightbox);
    }


    // remove any previously added content
    $('#lightbox').empty();
    // insert HTML content
    if (insertContent != null) {
        $('#lightbox').append(insertContent);
    }
    // insert AJAX content
    if (ajaxContentUrl != null) {
        // temporarily add a "Loading..." message in the lightbox
        $('#lightbox').append('<p class="loading">Loading...</p>');
        // request AJAX content
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: ajaxContentUrl,
            success: function (data) {
                // remove "Loading..." message and append AJAX content
                $('#lightbox').empty();
                $('#lightbox').append(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('AJAX Failure!');
            }
        });
    }
    // move the lightbox to the current window top + 100px
    $('#lightbox').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 100 + 'px');
    // display the lightbox
    $('#lightbox').show();
    $('#lightbox-shadow').show();
}

// close the lightbox
function closeLightbox() {
    // hide lightbox and shadow <div/>'s
    $('#lightbox').hide();
    $('#lightbox-shadow').hide();
    // remove contents of lightbox in case a video or other content is actively playing
    $('#lightbox').empty();
}
```

It looks like the script is trying to clear the previous content with empty(), but for some reason I am always getting the content that was initially loaded up. The rest of my script is fine as I am getting correct console.log returns.

So if I load the lightbox up, then close it, then click a button which attempts to change any element inside the lightbox. No effect.

Any hints for this? I'll post the full script if it's not clear. But basically, it seems as though I need to remove any reference to my original DOM element selection, and reselect it?

Edit: here's the full block of code I'm using:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
var cookieControl = new Object();

cookieControl.buttonAction = addOrRemove;
cookieControl.setFields = setFields;
cookieControl.countOptions = 0;
cookieControl.newPage = onPageReload;
cookieControl.setAll = setAll;
cookieControl.option;
cookieControl.updateBag = updateBag;

cookieControl.design = jQuery.cookie('design');
cookieControl.print = jQuery.cookie('print');
cookieControl.web = jQuery.cookie('web');
cookieControl.strategy = jQuery.cookie('strategy');
cookieControl.development = jQuery.cookie('development');

// JS variables to track set on current page
cookieControl.jsDesign = 0;
cookieControl.jsPrint = 0;
cookieControl.jsWeb = 0;
cookieControl.jsStrategy = 0;
cookieControl.jsDevelopment = 0;
// END

cookieControl.setFields();
cookieControl.newPage();

cookieControl.updateBag();

function updateBag(){
    if( cookieControl.countOptions > 0 ){
        $('.basket-icon').addClass('blue-bag');
    }else{
        $('.basket-icon').removeClass('blue-bag');
    }
}

function onPageReload(){
    if( cookieControl.design == 1){ cookieControl.countOptions++; $('.add-to-enquiry:eq(0)').addClass('remove-cookie').html('remove from enquiry <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">'); }
    if( cookieControl.print == 1){ cookieControl.countOptions++; $('.add-to-enquiry:eq(1)').addClass('remove-cookie').html('remove from enquiry <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">'); }
    if( cookieControl.web == 1){ cookieControl.countOptions++; $('.add-to-enquiry:eq(2)').addClass('remove-cookie').html('remove from enquiry <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">'); }
    if( cookieControl.strategy == 1){ cookieControl.countOptions++; $('.add-to-enquiry:eq(3)').addClass('remove-cookie').html('remove from enquiry <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">'); }
    if( cookieControl.development == 1){ cookieControl.countOptions++; $('.add-to-enquiry:eq(4)').addClass('remove-cookie').html('remove from enquiry <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">'); }

    $('.number-options-added').text( cookieControl.countOptions );
}

function setAll(){
    jQuery.cookie( 'design' , 1, { path: '/'});
    jQuery.cookie( 'web' , 1, { path: '/'});
    jQuery.cookie( 'print' , 1, { path: '/'});
    jQuery.cookie( 'strategy' , 1, { path: '/'});
    jQuery.cookie( 'development' , 1, { path: '/'});

    $('.number-options-added').text( 5 );
}

$('.add-to-enquiry').click(function(){
    var pos = $(this).index('.add-to-enquiry');
    cookieControl.buttonAction( pos );
    cookieControl.updateBag();
});


$('.add-all-options').click(function(){
    cookieControl.setAll(); 
    cookieControl.updateBag();
    alert('All services have been added to your enquiry!');
});


function setFields(){
    if(cookieControl.design == 1 || cookieControl.jsDesign == 1){
        $('#design_field').val("design");
    }

    if(cookieControl.print == 1 || cookieControl.jsPrint == 1){
        $('#print_field').val("print");
    }

    if(cookieControl.web == 1 || cookieControl.jsWeb == 1){
        $('#web_field').val("web");
    }

    if(cookieControl.strategy == 1 || cookieControl.jsStrategy == 1){
        $('#strategy_field').val("strategy");
    }

    if(cookieControl.development == 1 || cookieControl.jsDevelopment == 1){
        $('#development_field').val("development");
    }
}

function addOrRemove( pos ){

    if(pos == 0){
        cookieControl.option = 'design';
    }else if(pos == 1){
        cookieControl.option = 'print';
    }else if(pos == 2){
        cookieControl.option = 'web';
    }else if(pos == 3){
        cookieControl.option = 'strategy';
    }else if(pos == 4){
        cookieControl.option = 'development';
    }

    // remove cookie
    if($('.add-to-enquiry').eq(pos).hasClass('remove-cookie')){

        $('.add-to-enquiry').eq(pos).removeClass('remove-cookie');
        $('.add-to-enquiry').eq(pos).html('add to enquiry <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">');

        jQuery.removeCookie( cookieControl.option, { path: '/'} );

            if(pos == 0){
                cookieControl.jsDesign = 0;
            }else if(pos == 1){
                cookieControl.jsPrint = 0;
            }else if(pos == 2){
                cookieControl.jsWeb = 0;
            }else if(pos == 3){
                cookieControl.jsStrategy = 0;
            }else if(pos == 4){
                cookieControl.jsDevelopment = 0;
            }

        cookieControl.countOptions--;
        $('.number-options-added').text( cookieControl.countOptions );
    }else{
        $('.add-to-enquiry').eq(pos).addClass('remove-cookie');
        $('.add-to-enquiry').eq(pos).html('remove from enquiry <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">');

        jQuery.cookie( cookieControl.option, 1, { path: '/'});

            if(pos == 0){
                cookieControl.jsDesign = 1;
            }else if(pos == 1){
                cookieControl.jsPrint = 1;
            }else if(pos == 2){
                cookieControl.jsWeb = 1;
            }else if(pos == 3){
                cookieControl.jsStrategy = 1;
            }else if(pos == 4){
                cookieControl.jsDevelopment = 1;
            }

        cookieControl.countOptions++;
        $('.number-options-added').text( cookieControl.countOptions );

    }


    cookieControl.setFields();

}

theform = $('#theform');
jQuery("#contactForm").validate();

 });
```

A lot of this isn't relevant to my problem, but I'm assuming it'll make more sense to see my code in it's entirety.

The div with id 'theform' around it containts actual form. This seems irrelevant, though, as my problem is not with updating the form but updating anything inside the lightbox once it's been called for the first time. As you can see, my checkFields function is called correctly and if I return the info with console.log I get the correct data back. But it doesn't affect my form.

Comment: Please show us the code where you create the lightbox, close the lightbox, attempt to change the contents, then show the lightbox again.  As you can see, `closeLightbox()` clears the contents, so any modifications you made are lost.  If you then open the lightbox again by passing a URL, it will load fresh content (which will not have your modifications in it).

Comment: I'm not passing in a URL but a DOM element. But I take it my problem is occurring due to the closeLightbox function then? The content changes between lightbox calls, why wouldn't it show the updated content upon being called? Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to manually reinitialize your lightbox. 
What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the one above. That's it in it's entirety. I found it on some guy's site and it works great, except I need to refresh whatever it's showing, and for some reason I cannot..